# extern "C" usage (placement of tag)

Tags: c++, g++, extern

is there a difference between the following:

```
// c_header.h
void foo(void);
// main.cpp
extern "C" {
#include "c_header.h"
}
void main(void)
{
    foo();
}
```

and

```
// c_header.h
extern "C" {
void foo(void);
}
// main.cpp
#include "c_header.h"
void main(void)
{
    foo();
}
```

are both function calls to foo not c++ mangled?

Comment: Both are not mangled.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a difference. First example is an example of a terrible code, while second is a proper way of doing this.

To understand why I am saying so, consider how many translation units are potentially including this header. Because if you know for a fact there will only be one, you do not even need to worry about mangling.

However, if the `c_header` is also expected to be seen by C compiler, those `extern "C"` directives need to be hidden behind `#ifdef ___cplusplus`.

Comment: Isn't the whole reason for this because you want to use the same object and header with both C and C++ compilers? Why else would you need C linkage?

Comment: Did you mean "expected to be seen by a C compiler" in your last sentence?  AFAIK it's the C compiler you need to hide those `extern "C"` directives from, not the C++ compiler.

Comment: @MilesBudnek, you are absolutely correct, thanks for noticing. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference.  Remember that `#include` is handled by the preprocessor; the compiler sees exact same code in both cases when it compiles the preprocessed main.cpp.

P.S. Of course from code style/maintainability perspective you don't want to wrap `#include` in `extern "C"`. That is mostly reserved for special cases e.g. when you need to include a 3rd party pure C header without modifying it.

Comment: excactly, this is what id like to to, i use 3th party c code, that has functions __weak declaired, where im supposed to implement the function, and hope it will be linked correctly.